# how to use ImageResizer with asp.net cor 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, imageresizer

I used ImageResizer with asp.net mvc befor, I try to use it with asp.net core 2 project but it dose not work

when i call image with parameters it should resize but it dose not
https://localhost:44380/Data/Images/3fecc7e0-f84d-443c-aa55-be6f7b3bad02.jpg?w=400&h=200&mode=crop&scale=both

when i install ImageResizer from nuget I see an yallow mark on nuget folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Imageflow.NET Server is the .NET Core equivalent to ImageResizer, but is much faster and produces much smaller image files. See https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server

If you want to do your own middleware, use Imageflow.NET directly. See https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet